# Can't scroll on scrollpane - Vertical box alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout, scrollpane

I have a window with 4 textpanes, that goes out of the window vertically. The textpanes are inside a JPanel, which is inside a scrollbar. My problem is, that the scroller doesn't appear. I am guessing, that it's because I have set the jPanel layout to absolute. If I change the layout however, I don't have control over the textpanes height and placement on Y axis.

Here is what my window looks like. I want to be able to scroll down to see all 4 textpanes:
[image]

Here is my simplified code:

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 540);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    // Scroll Pane
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 503);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    // JPanel container for the text panes
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    // There is 4 TextPanes, that goes out of the window vertically.
    // I want to have control over height and spacing between textpanes.
    JTextPane txt1 = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane txt2 = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane txt3 = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane txt4 = new JTextPane();
    txt1.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 150);
    txt2.setBounds(0, 200, 500, 150);
    txt3.setBounds(0, 400, 500, 150);
    txt4.setBounds(0, 600, 500, 150);
    txt1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    txt2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    txt3.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    txt4.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel.add(txt1);
    panel.add(txt2);
    panel.add(txt3);
    panel.add(txt4);
```

SOLUTION (Edit):

I set the jPanel to a vertical box layout instead of absolute, and defined the width of the textpanes using "preferred size" instead of using bounds. As i result my textpanes are growing out of the window, where i can scroll down to view them all! Credit goes to @camickr

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` I could almost predict that I'd be seeing this. There's your problem in a nutshell. Get rid of all null layouts, all `setBounds` and instead use the layout managers and component properties correctly and your problem will go away. JScrollPanes do not work well with null layouts, as you're finding out.

Comment: A kludge is to set the jpanel's preferred size, but that is not a viable long-term solution. Again the best solution is to learn to use and then use the layout managers.

Comment: Layout managers are there for the programmer's convenience. They are much easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: *I don't have control over the text panes height and placement * - you need to use the appropriate layout manager or nested panels using multiple layout managers. We don't know what your real requirement is. Are you trying to make all text panes the same height, in which case you could use a GridLayout. If they are different sizes, then you could use a vertical BoxLayout or GridBagLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the reply. All the textpanes will have the same sizes. Problem is with all the layout managers i have tried, it fits all text panes into the scrollpane. So if i have 10 textpanes they shrink down to tiny textpanes to be able to fit. I want to be able to specify a height and be able to scroll down the scroll panel to see them all.

Comment: A vertical BoxLayout will work. As suggested above you can set the "preferred size" of each JTextPane to the same value, then you just add the text pane to the panel that is using the BoxLayout. You then add the panel to the scrollpane. You where given a link to a simple example. Did you try executing that code? All you need to do is change the layout and use a JTextPane instead of a JButton. Also, if you only have plain text than you can use a JTextArea and just specify the number of line you want which is better than trying to specify a preferred size.

Comment: @camickr You're an absolute legend, worked perfectly! My problem before was that I tried to set the size of the JTextPanes using bounds. Specifying the size using "preferred size" solved the problem. If you post it as a solution, I will pick it as the right answer! Thanks a ton!